# Avoiding Duplicate Inserts into Database

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna avoid a duplicate reservation that has the same **Date** and **Spot**. How would I go about doing this if possible. I wanna make sure no two customers can make a reservation for the same **Spot** on the same **Day**.

```
   // Insert data into mysql
    $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(Confirmation, Fname, Lname, Gname, License, Floor, Spot )
    VALUES('$confirm_code', '$fname', '$lname', '$gname', '$license', '$floor', '$spot')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_errno() == 1062)
```

Comment: what would you call a duplicate reservation in that case? one that is in the same date? same date+time? intersection of hours in the day?

Comment: You haven't shown any information at all about you are handling "time".  What is your concept of time?  Daily blocks? Hourly blocks? Per-minute blocks?

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: create a unique index.  this of course means you will have to answer the question of what makes the row unique

Comment: I updated question with what would be a duplicated reservation

Comment: @Randy, Right now only Spot is unique, will i have to make Date and Time Unique also? I wanna make sure if some reserves today at 1, someone can still reservation that spot for tomorrow.

Comment: good start - but what if someone stays for two hours - then the next reservation for the spot in 1 hour is available or not? :)

Comment: @Randy-i will have it that they cant reserve for the same day until the employee moves the reservation to a Archive Table. This is for a school project.

Comment: I don't see a Date or Time field in your table structure. How/where are you storing that? So the is no way to prevent duplicates of `Date, Time In, and Spot.` when 2 of the columns are not there.

Comment: @Sean-i didnt add Time and Date yet, i wanna know if its possible and how can i go about doing it before adding those fields

Comment: It is possible, but you need to clarify your 'uniqueness'. What is the length of reservation? Is it  by day, hour, quarter hour, etc.

Comment: @Sean-for now i will have it by day. So if someone reserves spot 1-101 on 7/10/13 no on can reserve that spot that day only reserve for future dates.

Comment: If it is by day, then it is very simple. Create a `day` column. Then you can create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on your table - `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX spot ON table_name (Spot, Day)` -http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Comment: Will this allow people to reserve different spots on the same day? Will day be unique? @Sean

Comment: Yes, as long as you do a `UNIQUE INDEX` on both `Spot` AND `Day` together - `(Spot, Day)`. If you were to only do it on just `Day` or just `Spot`, it would prevent others from reserving other spots, or on different days.

Comment: k, i will try that and let you know back, so i would keep:  if (mysql_errno() == 1062) - @Sean

Comment: Yes, if there is a duplicate of `(Spot, Day)` is should return error code 1062.

Comment: @Sean, It Works! Thanks, can you reply as a answer so I can check off question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent duplicate entries use [`UNIQUE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html). By defining it with multiple rows you can can easily control your reservations. So by adding a `Day` column you can then do -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX spot ON table_name (Spot, Day)
```

This will only allow 1 reservation per day per spot.